# Selecting one thing at a time with jquery, out of ideas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, automatically generated with `Smarty`. The table has some settings:

- `slice` (number, it's a wheel)
- `coupon` (winning or losing)
- `slice label` (basically if you win what you win, for example 20% off)
- `coupon code` (20OFF, 50OFF etc)
- `slice color`

Every element listed is a `td`. I need to write a function that disables the coupon code field if you mark the slice label as losing, I made a function, however it disables all of them. I can't give each slice a certain class, they all have the same classes. `couponType` is the label, winning or losing and couponCode is the field I need to disable. Any ideas? Here's what I've written so far:

```
$('.couponType').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'losing') {                    
    $('.couponCode').closest('.couponCode').attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $('.couponCode').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include the exact HTML Markup from the browser that is generated and combine it with your script in a snippet to make a working example that shows the issue. `.closest()` should only select a single element but possibly `.couponCode` wraps around multiple elements,.. or not. Either way without the Markup its impossible to tell.

Comment: _“couponType is the label”_ - labels don’t have values (`$(this).val() == …`) ; I guess you are actually looking for the text content of the label?